# How to remove the following character "/" from service path

Tags: mongodb, fiware, fiware-cygnus

Good Morning!

Currently I have set up my structure in Fiware saving my historical records in MongoDB, for this I have been using Mlab as a hosting.
I attache the configuration file of my agent, the problem comes in that due to the mandatory character "/" of the service path I can not access the generated historical data, since it is a character not allowed for collections in MongoDB.

**agent_1.conf**

```
cygnus-ngsi.sources = http-source
cygnus-ngsi.sinks = mongo-sink
cygnus-ngsi.channels = mongo-channel

cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.channels = mongo-channel
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.port = 5050
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = default
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = /sevilla
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 2
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp

cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSIMongoSink
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.channel = mongo-channel
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.enable_encoding = false
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.enable_grouping = false
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.enable_name_mappings = false
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.enable_lowercase = false
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.data_model = dm-by-service-path
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.attr_persistence = row
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_hosts = ds******.mlab.com:35866
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_username = my_user
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_password = ********
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.db_prefix = sth_
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.collection_prefix = sth_
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.batch_size = 1
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.batch_timeout = 30
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.batch_ttl = 10
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.data_expiration = 0
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.collections_size = 0
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.max_documents = 0
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.ignore_white_spaces = true

cygnus-ngsi.channels.mongo-channel.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.channels.CygnusMemoryChannel
cygnus-ngsi.channels.mongo-channel.capacity = 1000
cygnus-ngsi.channels.mongo-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

Is there any way for Cygnus to remove the "/" character from the service path?

Error: http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagedata.php?url=http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/9827048captura-de-pantalla.png

**SOLUTION: You just have to change the enconding to true in the agent configuration**

```
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.enable_encoding = true
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: The slash ('/') is a valid character for MongoDB collections, as stated in the official documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/limits/#Restriction-on-Collection-Names

Comment: It seems it is a problem with the visualization tool you are using for MongoDB. Which is it?

Comment: Thank you very much frb for your quick response!
For our case and using the documentation https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/cygnus-ngsi/flume_extensions_catalogue/ngsi_mongo_sink.md we have found that in the section MongoDB databases naming conventions it appears that the use of characters /, \,., "and $ is not accepted in the databases.
I have already solved my problem and to collaborate with all I leave the solution in case some other user has the same problem with the connection between MongoDB and Cygnus.
Thank you for your collaboration!

Comment: The slash is forbidden in MongoDB database names, that's why Cygnus composes database names from the FIWARE service (which does not contain any slash). On the other hand, the slash is not forbidden in MongoDB collection names, which are composed by Cygnus based on the FIWARE service path (which contains a initial slash). Being said that, if your viewer has any problem with MongoDB collections containing the slash, you are right the only option for you is to enable the encoding of non ASCII characters through `enable_encoding=true` configuration.

Comment: BTW, you can answer yourself by putting the solution in a proper answer post :)

Comment: Fix to my comment above: I wanted to say "non alpha-numeric characters".